# Determine if element has children with X tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I am looping through some elements and need to determine if an element has a child(grandchild?) with the li tag, like in the information element below. The li elements will vary in id so I am not referencing them that way. I am currently looping through the li elements and if I check for children it always returns true because there are "a" tag children, I just want to check for 'lil' tag children.

```
            <ul id="navMenu">
                <li id="home"><a href="#home" rel="ajax">Home</a></li>
                <li id="information"><a href="#information" rel="ajax">Information</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#credits" rel="ajax">Credits</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#lorem_ipsum" rel="ajax">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#contact" rel="ajax">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Here is what I have now...

```
        $('#test').load('../common.html #navMenu', function() {
            $.each($("#test #navMenu li"), function(i,v) {
                var theElement = $(v);
                if ($(theElement).children('li')){
                    alert('This Element has children');
                }
            });
        });
```

Thank you once again,
Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(theElement).children('li')` returns a jQuery object which always passes an `if` clause, even when it's empty.

Moreover, you want `.find`, since `.children` only returns direct children and not grandchildren.

So:

```
if ($(theElement).find('li').length > 0) {
```

or:

```
if ($(theElement).find('li').length) {
// 0 won't pass an if clause, and all other numbers will, so you can eliminate `> 0`
```

Comment: Cool tip about 0 not passing an if clause, seems very obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 2):

You could try -

```
$('#test').load('../common.html #navMenu', function() {
    $.each($("#test #navMenu li"), function(i,v) {
        var theElement = $(v);
        if ($(theElement).find('li').length > 0){
            alert('This Element has children');
        }
    });
});
```

`find` will go deeper into the current element than `children` which only searches one level down.

Comment: Thank you works perfect. And I discovered a new function, "find".

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
> var theElement = $(v); 
> if ($(theElement).children('li')) {  
>   alert('This Element has children'); 
> }
```

doesn't `$(v)` return an jQuery object? So `$(theElement)` is redundant.

Anyhow, if `v` is a reference to one of the elements passed to *.each*, then you can replace all of the above with:

```
if (v.getElementsByTagName('li').length) {
  /* v has li descendants */
]
```

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, theElement is redundant and I have removed it. This also works very well. I am not sure which I will use but it is always good to see alternatives, if not just to learn from them.

Answer (score 0):

you could also add the extra li to your query: "#test #navMenu li li"

Comment: I need to iterate through the parent elements also, I think this would miss them.